# How to access mean/median values of cross validations from a S4 object in R?

Tags: r, prediction, r-s4

I am working with the `penalized` and `ROCR` packages in R and have a prediction S4 object containing values from 200 cross validations. I am attaching the structure here.I figured how to see the names of the slots, as below:

```
names(getSlots(class(c.pred)))

 [1] "predictions" "labels"      "cutoffs"     "fp"          "tp"      
"tn"          "fn"          "n.pos"     "n.neg"       "n.pos.pred" 
"n.neg.pred"
```

However, I cannot figure out how to extract the mean/median for each of these slots..like for fp,tp,etc. I would have to unlist each slot and get the summary, I guess,but am a bit lost.
[Structure of c.pred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wllnC.png)